# Running method inside of a function on a node

Tags: javascript, methods, jquery-selectors, html5-video, nodes

I'm having trouble with understanding how the code snippet below works. 
    const video = player.querySelector('.viewer');

```
function togglePlay() {
    const method = video.paused ? 'play' : 'pause';
    video[method];
}
togglePlay() //starts playing video
```

The exact part that I don't understand is video[method], how does it work? I've tried to google it, but no luck so far. Are we just adding a method to the video object? If so, why we invoke togglePlay() it starts playing video?!

Comment: Did you mean to put parenthesis - () - after video[method]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way this works is by accessing the properties on video object. This means we use the video like an array. If the the video is paused the we find the play method otherwise we find the pause method. We are not creating new methods we are just finding the methods that already exist on the object.

if you wanted to you could rewrite the code to something like

```
function togglePlay() {
     if(video.paused) {
          video.play() // could also be written as video["play"]()
     } else {
          video.pause() // could also be written as video["pause"]()
     }
}
```

To make the togglePlay method work like you wrote it you have to change the last line in togglePlay function to this.

video[method] to video[method]();

```js
const video = document.getElementById("video");
function togglePlay() {
    const method = video.paused ? 'play' : 'pause';
    video[method]();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
  <button onclick="togglePlay()">toggle play</button>
</body>
</html>
```